# manually creating an ubuntu 12 sha512 password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

I'm looking to manually generate a password to edit into `/etc/shadow`

Can someone tell me how I can create a hashed password that works in **Ubuntu 12** with `SHA512` encryption?

I'm trying to migrate some user accounts to a different installation and I don't have the OS, just the hard drive , so I need to manually create some password entries in `/etc/shadow`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - it can be done a variety of ways with any interface that has access to the crypt library... you prepend $6$ plus an 8 character salt + $ to the SHA512 hashed version of the same.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the password is only a hash so you generate them by using a simple sha512 hash generator and enter your desired password into there http://www.miniwebtool.com/sha512-hash-generator/

Comment: sha512 is also not encryption it is used to generate a hash